# Distribution of joint Gaussian conditional on their sum of squares

Tags: probability-distributions, random-matrices, gaussian, norms

Given a random gaussian matrix $\mathbf{X}$ with zero mean matrix and covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$, and two deterministic matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. If I know the value of $\|\mathbf{AX}\|_F^2$, how could I get the pdf of $\|\mathbf{BX}\|_F^2$ ($\|\mathbf{P}\|_F^2$ is the $L^2$ norm of matrix $\mathbf{P}$)?

In my opinion, since $\mathbf{X}$ is a random gaussian matrix, $\|\mathbf{AX}\|_F^2$ follows chi-square distribution and its pdf can be calculated. However, if I obtain the value of the random variable $\|\mathbf{AX}\|_F^2$ without knowing specific $\mathbf{X}$, the pdf of $\mathbf{X}$ and the pdf of $\|\mathbf{BX}\|_F^2$ are not obvious.

What I want to know is, **what are the distributions of $\mathbf{X}$ and $\|\mathbf{BX}\|_F^2$ given $\|\mathbf{AX}\|_F^2=a$**? Or, is there any method to get the pdf of $\|\mathbf{BX}\|_F^2$ given $\|\mathbf{AX}\|_F^2=a$ without calculating the pdf of $\mathbf{X}$.

I have learned the pdf of $\mathbf{X}$ given $S=s$, where $S$ is the sum of all elements of $\mathbf{X}$ from [this Math.SE Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784531/distribution-of-joint-gaussian-conditional-on-their-sum?rq=1), but it seems quite different from this question.